# KeyError for stdnum.isin.is_valid() function in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
stdnum.isin.is_valid(df_final.loc[0,'ISIN_Final'])
```

I am using the above code to check if I have valid ISIN in the first row of ISIN_Final column; it gives me following error

> KeyError: 0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is probably because your index is not a range of indices? Try with `df_final.iloc[0,n]`, `n` being the position of the column

Comment: Thanks a lot. This does work.

Comment: Ah you're welcome :)